# How to check for mesh overlap?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, physics, meshcollider

I'm creating a level editor in Unity. I need to detect when an object is intersecting another as I don't want to allow the user to place an object when it is colliding with something else.

In the below diagam, there is a corner road piece and a tree. The dashed red line represents the mesh bounds of the road and the blue dashed line represents the mesh bounds of the tree.

[image]

My current approach is to use `Physics.OverlapBox` with `mesh.bounds`. In the diagram, visually, it is clear that the tree does not overlap the road. However, the bounds do overlap, therefore I cannot place the tree there.

Whats the best way to check if they are actually colliding in an efficient way? The level editor could potentially have thousands of objects.

EDIT:
I have since tried using [Physics.ComputePenetration](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html). Primitive-primitive checks work ok, primitive-mesh collider checks work ok, but mesh collider-mesh collider checks fail. From what I understand a concave mesh collider cannot interact with another concave mesh collider. Is there a workaround for this or must I momentarily make it convex before checking overlap? I just don't want to lose the accuracy of the concave collider.

Comment: Tests with concave colliders are vastly more expensive than convex ones, so it's usually a good idea to decompose your concave colliders into multiple convex or primitive pieces wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I first use `Physics.OverlapSphere` to get the nearby colldiers. Then for a more precise calculation I use [Physics.ComputePenetration](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html).

However, some of my assets utilize concave mesh colliders. As stated in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html), a concave mesh collider cannot collide with another concave mesh collider. To fix this, I momentarily make the mesh collider convex before calling the overlap sphere.

Comment: If your issue is solved, could you mark your answer as correct, to prevent it from being bumped to the homepage?